# Оставить только целые от десятичной дроби

Tags: arduino, float

Имеются данные с датчика температуры (arduino + ds18b20 + [библиотека dallas temp](https://github.com/milesburton/Arduino-Temperature-Control-Library)),

```
float temp = 26.23;
```

Нужно записать в переменную **только целую часть**, то есть **26**, выводить умею: `Serial.println (temp,0);` а вот в переменную записать не могу.

Comment: А вам точно надо именно отсечь дробную часть, а не округлить до целых? Если да, можно поинтересоваться почему?

Comment: @4per Точно отсечь дробную часть, так как температура (в дробной части) очень часто меняется и для сравнения с предшествующей мне лучше использовать целую часть

Comment: В чем проблема прикастить? так `(int)temp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделал след. образом с помощью [cast](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Cast):
Ввел дополнительную переменную `int inttemp;` затем конвертировал переменную **temp** с **float** значением (**26.23**) в **integer** `inttemp = (int)temp;` и на выходе получил **26**

Comment: Плохой совет. Зачем держать какие-то временные переменные? Там и так места с гулькин нос!

Comment: самый простой вариант

Answer (score 7):

**Float** это сразу почти **1кб** места в скетче + еще 4 байта на каждую переменную. Не надо так... Обычная операция *100 при получении данных и /%100 при выводе их на экран, решает вашу проблему

Answer (score 0):

Выдача гугл http://arduino.ru/forum/programmirovanie/rabota-s-float

> "пешком" нужное преобразование можно сделать следующим образом:

```
float v;
long V;
...
v=13.67;
V=round(v*10);
V/10 // целая часть числа
V%10 // дробная часть числа (1 позиция)
```

> А еще легче просто не доводить до флоат. в авр нет флоата как такового и в 99% случаев можно обойтись и без него.

Comment: что значит "не доводить до флоат"?

Comment: не использовать его вообще, я полагаю

Answer (score 0):

я бы сделал вот так

```
int temp = (int)26.23;
Serial.println (temp,0);
```